# Prioritize WHERE clause over 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, vertica

I have some table

```
CREATE TABLE some_table(row_id int, id_1 varchar, id_2 varchar, some_value varchar)
```

Columns id_1 and id_2 can be one of this values - 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'.

Sample data:

```
|row_id|id_1 |id_2 |some_value|
|  1   |  a  |  b  |  abcd    |
|  2   |  b  |  c  |  bcde    |
|  3   |  d  |  a  |  cdef    |
|  4   |  c  |  d  |  def     |
|  5   | null|  a  |  efg     |
|  6   |  b  | null|  fgh     |
|  7   |  c  | null|  ghi     |
|  8   | null|  d  |  hik     |
|  9   | null| null|  ikl     |
```

Result that I want:

```
|row_id|id_1 |id_2 |some_value|
|  1   |  a  |  b  |  abcd    |
|  2   |  b  |  c  |  bcde    |
|  3   |  d  |  a  |  cdef    |
|  5   | null|  a  |  efg     |
|  6   |  b  | null|  fgh     |
```

I need to choose row, if:

1. id_1 = 'a' OR id_1 = 'b'
2. If id_1 don't fit the condition 1, then id_2 = 'a' OR id_2 = 'b'
   I know that I can use some subqueries and unions like that:

```
WITH a_or_b_values AS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM some_table
    WHERE id_1 = 'a' or id_1 = 'b'
        or id_2 = 'a' or id_2 = 'b'
),
id_1_values AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM some_table
    WHERE id_1 = 'a' OR id_1 = 'b'
) SELECT * 
FROM some_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT row_id FROM id_1_values WHERE id_1_values.row_id = a_or_b_values.row_id)
UNION
SELECT * FROM id_1_values;
```

Is more efficient/elegant solution exists?

PS: I use Vertica/Postgres db, but this question is more about logic - solution for any db is acceptable

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your intention is not clear.  Also tag with the database you are using.  Why does your code compare `id_2` to `''`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I added some samples, thank you for your support))

Comment: By "prioriize", do you mean that when multiple rows (with different conditions) are found, you only want one row?

Comment: @TheImpaler, in my case, "prioritize" means a priority of one column by another in condition

Comment: I fail to understand the prioritization. The conditions priority does not affect the result you are showing. Or does it? Maybe in the ordering of the result... I can't tell.

Comment: Vertica is something completely different than Postgres

Answer (score 0):

If you want *one* row in the result set, you can use `order by` and fetch one row:

```
select t.*
from t
where id_1 in ('a', 'b') or id_2 in ('a', 'b')
order by (case when id_1 in ('a', 'b') then 1 else 2 end)
offset 1 row fetch first one row only;
```

EDIT:

For your clarified question, I think you just want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id_1 in ('a', 'b') or
      t.id_2 in ('a', 'b');
```